# How to minify multiple files into one file using only uglifyjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, uglifyjs

I have tried to minify javascript files using uglifyjs into one file, but it's not working. I used $node uglifyjs.js to run the file. Below is the code in uglify.js

```
  var fs = require('fs');

  var uglifyjs = require('uglify-js');

  var files = ['app.js', 'geolocation.service.js'];

  var result = uglifyjs.minify(fs.readFileSync(files, 'utf8'));

 console.log(result.code);

 fs.writeFile("output.min.js", result.code, function(err){
 if(err){
  console.log(err);
  } else {
  console.log("File was successfully saved.");
 }
 });
```

When I run this code I get the following error message:

```
  fs.js:549
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), 
  mode);
             ^

   TypeError: path must be a string
   at TypeError (native)
   at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
   at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\uglify\uglify.js:7:33)
   at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
   at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
   at startup (node.js:134:18)
```

Comment: `fs.readFileSync(file[, options])` -- `file <string> | <Buffer> | <integer> filename or file descriptor`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown [here](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#conditional-compilation-api), `uglify.minify` requires that you pass in a `string` or a list of `string`s.

Your code:

```
var result = uglifyjs.minify(fs.readFileSync(files, 'utf8'));
```

Is trying to read several files at once, but `fs.readFileSync` only accepts one file.

So change your code to this:

```
var filesContents = ['app.js', 'geolocation.service.js'].map(function (file) {
    return fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
})

var result = uglifyjs.minify(filesContents);

if (result.error) {
    console.error("Error minifying: " + result.error);
}

fs.writeFile("output.min.js", result.code, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log("File was successfully saved.");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That totally did the job.